# Git branching to develop two application variations?

Tags: git

It's been requested that two version of my application be created, one with a slight variation on the original. To handle this, should I branch or is there another way to tackle this?

Comment: This is probably better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: In fact, here is the question that @RafałRawicki is probably referring to: [Choosing between Single or multiple projects in a git repository?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/302147/maintain-hundreds-of-customized-branches-over-master-branch)

Comment: Thank you @GregBurghardt, I was going to add another comment in the spirit of answers to this question.

Comment: @RafałRawicki when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a branch (git checkout -b ...).  Doing this will preserve your master branch (the original project) and create a carbon copy (at the same time) for you to work on, all the while keeping the original project in tact.

Comment: What happens if during development on the branch I resolve an issue that the master would benefit from?

Comment: @JacobMason in that case you can just merge the work from branch 'B' into branch 'A' (assuming branch 'A' is the master branch)

Comment: But then wouldn't the master become the variation and then I have lost my unique variation?

Comment: @JacobMason yes, that is correct.  So the next option, then, would be to make two branches off of master and then work on those two branches as your 'project variations'.  if you find something you like in branch B or C that needs to be in branch A (the master branch) then yes, the unique variation will be overwritten, but that is the point of a git merge

Comment: You could also (if your beneficial changes are not hugely extensive) do a git add -p to only retrieve those changes that you want to merge